# how to calculate N in "make -jN" ? for full utilisation of CPU

Tags: android, performance, makefile, cpu, cpu-speed

Need to build android source build with full CPU utilisation.
 
For that, how to calculate **N** in " **make -jN** " ? 
**Sample CPUinfo**:

[image: cpuinfo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cores=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)
make -j${cores}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 1):

Your Linux distro should come with the command `nprocs`, or at least `nprocs` should be easily installable.  If you don't want to require `nprocs`, this shell command will give you the number of cores in the box (including hyper-threaded ones): `ls -d /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-9]*|wc -l`

Comment: Thanks for the info :)